google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(...).withFailureHandler(...) is not a function

I'm integrating my Google Apps Script library into another guest Google Apps Script.

Both the library and the guest script are tied-to Google Sheets.

The library has a sidebar.html file, which is called into the guest script like this:
Guest Script > Script.gs
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('My Menu')
      .addItem('Open Sidebar', 'showSidebar')
      .addToUi();
}

function showSidebar() {
    myLibrary.showSidebar();
}

This works and creates the UI menu, and clicking it opens the sidebar.html from the library, which runs as an HTML file with all front-end JavaScript <script>s inside of it.

In the sidebar.html file (in the library) I have a JavaScript function to communicate with a server-side function through google.script.run, like this:
Library > sidebar.html
<script>
    google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler((backendResponse) => {
            console.log('Successfully got backend response!');
        })
        .withFailureHandler((error) => {
            console.log('Error getting backend response!');
        })
        .myBackendFunctionName(someArgument);
</script>




This works alright when I run it in a Google Apps Script directly, but, when I run it from an integrated library, it throws the following error to the guest's console:

Uncaught TypeError:
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(...).withFailureHandler(...).myBackendFunctionName
is not a function

What am I doing wrong? and how can I fix that?

There is no function named myBackendFunctionName. Please ensure to include a [mcve]
